# Integer isn't being detected if it's in a list with another integer

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to create an economy system of my own, but when I try to assign an amount of money to the list containing the user's ID and balance, it can't detect the user's ID anymore so it creates multiple lists with the user's ID and balance.

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from replit import db
#from keepalive import keep_alive
from random import randint

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot('PREFIX',intents=intents)
db["users"] = [[883866317709512714], [155149108183695360]]

def checkuser(message): 
  if "users" in db.keys():
    id = message.author.id

    if id in db["users"] == True:
      print("User already in database")
    else:
      db["users"].append([id])
      print("User added to database")

  else:
    db["users"] = message.author.id
    print("Database created")
  

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("I'm in")
  print(client.user)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return


  if message.content == "OwOping":
    await message.channel.send("pong")


  if message.content == "OwObal":
    checkuser(message)
    id = [message.author.id]
    await message.channel.send(db["users"])
    index = db["users"].index(id)
    try: 
      db["users"][index][1] == True
    except IndexError:
      print("IndexError")
      bal = 100
      db["users"][index].append(bal)
    else:
      print("User already in database!")

    await message.channel.send("Your balance is " + str(db["users"][index][1]))
        

    

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f"{member} has joined")
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Member")
    print(role)
    await member.add_roles(role)
    




  

    
#keep_alive()
my_secret = os.environ['token']
token = os.environ.get("token")    
client.run(token)
```

I've considered making a list out of the user's ID, but I found that a bit to complicated and I encountered the exact same error.

Comment: My guess is that `message.author.id` is coming in as a string.  You are expecting integers.  And @JoranBeasley, they are already making a list out of it.

Comment: @TimRoberts your right i now see :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add numbers to `db["users"]`, but not lists. Then you can use `if id in db["users"] == True:` statement correctly.

And use a dictionary to record users' balances.

```
db["users"] = ['883866317709512714', '155149108183695360']

# for recording each user's money left
balances = {}
balances['883866317709512714'] = 50
balances['155149108183695360'] = 25

def checkuser(message): 
  if "users" in db.keys():
    id = message.author.id

    if id in db["users"] == True:
      print("User already in database")
    else:
      db["users"].append(id)
      print("User added to database")

  else:
    db["users"] = message.author.id
    print("Database created")
```

Comment: I've just tried that, and it seems to work but not for what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to make multiple lists containing the ID and money so that I can keep track of balances and the sort. For example, [id,balance], [id2,balance2] and so on.

Comment: I've revised my answer.

Answer (score 0):

just make user id in string like this :

```py
def checkuser(message): 
  if "users" in db.keys():
    id = message.author.id

    if str(id) in db["users"] == True: #added str(id)
      print("User already in database")
    else:
      db["users"].append([id])
      print("User added to database")

  else:
    db["users"] = message.author.id
    print("Database created")
```

Comment: I've tried that and it doesn't work, so I checked what it comes out as using the `Type()` function and it seems to return an integer as default.